# How to retrieve CIM instances from a Linux host using WinRM?

Tags: c#, wmi, winrm, wbem, wsman

I'm using WinRM API in an attempt to collect some CIM instances from several hosts running either Windows or Linux. My code works fine when connecting to a Windows host, but an exception is thrown if I try to connect to a Linux machine, which is running the SFCB CIM server. I can retrieve CIM instances from the Linux host just fine via WBEM, but not via WS-MAN/WinRM.

Here's sample code that gets `CIM_OperatingSystem` from a Windows host - this works fine:

```
WSMan wsman = new WSMan();
IWSManConnectionOptions options = (IWSManConnectionOptions)wsman.CreateConnectionOptions();               

try
{
    string remoteHost = "WindowsHost1";
    options.UserName = @"domain\User";                    
    options.Password = "somePwd";                                                           
    IWSManSession session = (IWSManSession)wsman.CreateSession(remoteHost, wsman.SessionFlagCredUsernamePassword(), options);

    try
    {
        IWSManEnumerator cimInstances = session.Enumerate("http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wmi/root/cimv2/CIM_OperatingSystem");

        // Enumerate returned CIM instances.
        while (!cimInstances.AtEndOfStream)
        {
            string item = cimInstances.ReadItem();                  
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(item);
            var resultSet = from e in doc.Elements() select e;

            foreach (var element in resultSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
    }
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(options);
}
```

If `remoteHost` points to a Linux machine (openSUSE VM in my example), here's what happens:

- if I specify the hostname only, i.e. `remoteHost = "myLinuxHost"`, `session.Enumerate()` fails:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path
>   was not found. at WSManAutomation.IWSManSession.Enumerate(Object
>   resourceUri, String filter, String dialect, Int32 flags)

I can ping the machine successfully, so it should be visible. However, the hostname is only mapped to its IP in my Windows `hosts` file. If I try to create a session to this machine with PowerShell, an error occurs as well:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $session = new-cimsession myLinuxHost -credential user
```

> new-cimsession : WinRM cannot process the request.  The following
>   error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the
>   computer myLinuxHost.  Verify that the computer exists on the network
>   and that the name provided is spelled correctly.

- if I specify the complete host URL (one that I can retrieve CIM instances with using WBEM), i.e. `remoteHost = "https://<ip>:5989"` or `remoteHost = "https://myLinuxHost:5989"` enumeration fails with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: A
>   security error occurred at
>   WSManAutomation.IWSManSession.Enumerate(Object resourceUri, String
>   filter, String dialect, Int32 flags)

Details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
HResult=-2147012721
Message=A security error occurred 
Source=Session
ErrorCode=-2147012721
StackTrace:
   at WSManAutomation.IWSManSession.Enumerate(Object resourceUri, String filter, String dialect, Int32 flags)
   at WSManTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After reading some manuals on how to establish a Powershell session to a non-WSMAN machine by using HTTPS CIMSessions, I have found that there is a parameter of type `CIMSessionOption` which can be constructed to use SSL, so that the actual connection is done via WBEM interface over HTTPS. The document is [here](http://www.systemcenter.ninja/2013/09/using-powershell-cim-sessions-to-query.html), the codes are as follows:

```
$UserName="root"
$Password="calvin" # default password
$DracIP="10.10.0.120" # supply your box's IP
$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText  -Force
$DracCred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName,$SecurePass 
# this just makes a PSCredential object to be used as a reference
$cimop=New-CimSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck -Encoding Utf8 -UseSsl
# this instruction creates a SSL-enabled option set with ignore certificate checks (Dells have self-signed certs on their side)
$Dracsession=New-CimSession -Authentication Basic -Credential $DracCred -ComputerName $DracIP -Port 443 -SessionOption $cimop -OperationTimeoutSec 10000000
Get-CimInstance -CimSession $Dracsession -ResourceUri "http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/root/dcim/DCIM_SystemView"
```

So, in order to make your C# program to connect via WBEM, you have to translate Powershell code that creates the CIMSessionOption and CIMSession using non-WSMAN method. In Powershell this should let you connect to the Linux machine if provided proper credentials. The `ResourceUri` parameter specifies what object you want to retrieve, and the proper URI should be taken from manuals on the target system.